# CPU frequency drops to and is capped at 0.48 GHz

Tags: dell, intel, performance, cpu, frequency

I have a Dell Inspiron 7348 (BIOS version A13, the most recent) and the CPU frequency is always capped at exactly 480 or 490 MHz. I had this same problem under win10 but modifying a registry key for this `intelppm` process did the trick, or so it appeared. Everything was just as laggy as before but the frequency wasn't limited.

Then I decided to install Ubuntu 20.04, and the problem still didn't go away. The laptop performs pretty well for the first couple of seconds after boot and then everything just lags out, which makes me think that there's perhaps a process that does it straight after booting up?

Here's a list of things I have tried:

1. Disabling Intel Speedstep. Made no difference.
2. Using `cpufreq` to set the mode to Performance. Didn't work either.
3. Changing the minimum frequency. Didn't work.
4. Disabling `intel_powerclamp` and doing away with it altogether. Also didn't work

I also used prime95 to put the cpu on 100% load and the frequency was still capped. Any ideas as to what might be causing it?

Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistakes as this is my first post here. I couldn't find any other posts suggesting anything that solved my problem.

Edit:

[image: cpu, scaling governer, and scaling driver]

Comment: Please provide the motherboard model. Did you try booting into BIOS and changing some settings there?

Comment: dell does limit CPU frequency sometimes. Additionally, we need your CPU make and model, your CPU freqency scaling driver, and your scaling governor. Edit your question with output from: `grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo` ; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` ; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: I can't find the exact model number for the motherboard but it has an ```i7-5500U```. Yes I have changed every setting I could find that might've contributed to the problem. Turned Speedstep on and off and changed the battery power mode form adaptive to standard.

Comment: @DougSmythies as it turns out after posting I came across another post that outlined this same problem and found a solution that involves removing the battery and installing it again. So far it appears to be working and there isn't any limit on the frequency. Should I link that post in an answer to my own question or can I just delete this?

Comment: Give us the link, and we'll vote to close this question with that link as the reason. That way your up-voters, and future readers, will be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @DougSmythies here you go: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092481/cpu-frequency-at-minimum-both-on-ac-and-battery-bios-problem