# Disable Hyperthreading, p-state and c-state drivers and CPU frequency scaling

Tags: scaling, frequency

I am trying to disable de p-state and c-state drivers on my desktop, i did what is described in this topic: [Disable CPU frequency scaling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523640/how-i-can-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-and-set-the-system-to-performance)

Then i changed the grub-file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 idle=poll"
```

And after this i updated the grub and added `governor="performance"` in the cpufrequtils file.

Besides, I did all the aforementioned in another computer and they are working(i think), so this is the expected output for cpufreq-info:

[PC where the changes took effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwZhN.png)

And here is the output i get on this one:

[PC where the changes were ignored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnLLt.png)

In the end it looks like this computer is ignoring the changes i'm doing, any idea why?

Moreover the uname-a displays the following:

In the PC i'm trying to change:    `Linux oai-test1 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

In the PC the changes took effect: `Linux oai-test2 3.19.0-61-lowlatency #69~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 9 10:15:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of 'uname -a' from each computer along with system model number and make?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by system model number and make?

Comment: System model and make, is Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 AE. I would switch your kernel off if low latency to generic to fix the problem.

Comment: Neither of your kernels are giving you protection from 'Dirty COW' security fix as they predate Oct 21/2016

Comment: Kernel 3.19 is very old and I'll have to research if it even includes Intel pstate support. If the machine isn't freezing I wouldn't even worry about Intel idling.

Comment: the thing is i have to use this kernel, and it was installed in the computer the changes took effect. I am using Open Air Interface software and they require this OS and this kernel for support.

Comment: I understand completely. The solution is a different CPU if you can't get the freezing to stop. It is freezing up right?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Not freezing, in the computer that the changes took effect, the frequencies shown by i7z don't change more than 1Hz, and in this one they change a lot. And i'm sorry, the one with the 3.19 kernel is the one that the changes worked, and the kernel was installed after them.

Comment: @JoaoAmaral I see you came from oai too! I would like to know if you managed to fix it since I'm facing the same issue on my system too. I'm using the `4.40-79-generic` kernel