# Ubuntu 16.04.2 Stuck at Very Low Frequency

Tags: 16.04, performance, cpu

My Dell T7610 with 2 x E5-2650V2 processors (each with 8 real cores, regular 2.6GHz, turbo 3.4GHz) is stuck at 1.2GHz and I am unable to get it to go faster. How do I get it to go at full speed?

I have followed the advice here to set the governor to "performance":
[similar question from a year ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523640/how-i-can-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-and-set-the-system-to-performance?noredirect=1&lq=1). Except I was unable to do the "sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable" command as I got this error:

> `insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script`"ondemand"`overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).`
>   `insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (2 3 4 5) of script`"ondemand"`overrides LSB defaults (empty).`

And for a while the frequencies did go up, but now they are back at 1.2GHz and do not budge.

Geekbench verifies that this makes a real difference: [Geekbench at 1.2GHz](http://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/2137285) and [Geekbench at higher freqs](http://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/2137605). As you can see, I was able to get it to run faster for a while but then it went back to 1.2GHz and the Geekbench load did nothing to change that.

I get this info for each of the 16 processor cores:

> analyzing CPU 10:
>    driver: intel_pstate
>    CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 10
>    CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 10
>    maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
>    hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.40 GHz
>    available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
>    current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.40 GHz.
>                    The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
>                    within this range.
>    current CPU frequency: 1.20 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
>    boost state support:
>      Supported: yes
>      Active: yes
>     3100 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
>     3200 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
>     3300 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
>     3400 MHz max turbo 1 active cores

I have tried to adjust the minimum frequency, but the actual frequency stuck way below this minimum:

> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
>   2400000

Comment: Rebooted the computer and the frequencies worked fine for a while until at some point they all went to 1.2GHz and stayed there. The transition actually happened under load. Nothing seems to get them out of 1.2GHz. This is not thermal throttling as CPU temperatures were below 40 Celsius when the frequencies all went down.

Comment: So the computer keeps fluctuating between two states: 1) all cores stuck at 1.2GHz or 2) all cores flexibly changing frequencies. The computer switches between these states completely independently of temperature or load. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same problem here. I've been trying to sort it out but nothing seems to fix it. A reboot is only a temporary fix...