# How to change the CPU escalator configuration that Ubuntu has originally

Tags: kernel, configuration, cpufreq

I don't want a command line solution that includes *installing* anything at all. Ubuntu configures the CPU governor in a **configuration file** AFAIK. I want to locate and change the file correctly.

I don't want to disable the default governor instead, learn how to **correctly set** one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable "ondemand" CPU scaling daemon](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3924/disable-ondemand-cpu-scaling-daemon)

Comment: A better question is what makes you think you need to change ?

Comment: And another good question is why would this represent a disadvantage?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling

Comment: @user3005629 - Depends on how you set it and what you want to accomplish, no ? Running your CPU at full speed when it is not needed == watse of power and heat. Restricting ondemand means you are crippling your CPU.  see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/cpufreq_governors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is `/etc/init.d/ondemand`.

Without any additional packages, you can manipulate the frequency scaling governors using primitive commands.

First, determine what available governors you have available:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
```

Perhaps see what you currently have:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

And then, if different than what you want, just set one of the other available governors, in this example performance:

```
$ sudo su
# for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "performance" > $file; done
# exit
```

Example:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
$ sudo su
# for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "performance" > $file; done
# exit
exit
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

Comment: A little more information please =)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Based on the edited question, I added more information.

Comment: Still gets overwritten, this is not changing the actual original configuration

Comment: @user3005629: Put a sleep for 70 seconds into it. That way the ondemand script, that sleeps for 60 seconds will be finished first.

Comment: @DougSmythies I solved my immediate situation by changing the priority of the user instead.