# How should I setup Tuned-adm?

Tags: power-management, cpu

So the simple answer could be just install tuned `apt install tuned`

I wonder if the ondemand service would collide with tuned-adm so being it disabling the service before installing tuned.

This is what I think I should do

```
systemctl stop ondemand
systemctl disable ondemand
apt install tuned
```

I want to confirm this because I have no documentation saying I should do this.

Comment: Based on this thread (and Tuned documentation), I don't see why they would collide. Ondemand **is not a power management tool**, just a speed tuning tool for the processor (https://askubuntu.com/questions/3924/disable-ondemand-cpu-scaling-daemon). Have you tried running them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two processes don't really conflict with each other. `ondemand.service` focuses on setting the CPU Frequency Scaling governor.:

```
$ systemctl status ondemand
● ondemand.service - LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ondemand; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-10-31 05:30:09 MDT; 1 weeks 3 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Oct 31 05:30:08 alien systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "o
Oct 31 05:30:09 alien systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "on
```

---

Tuned on the other hand focuses on optimizing performance of storage devices (including swap):

### [The Tuned Project](https://tuned-project.org/)

#### Tuned is a system tuning service for Linux. It:

- monitors connected devices using the udev device manager
- tunes system settings according to a selected profile
- supports various types of configuration like sysctl, sysfs, or kernel boot command line parameters, which are integrated in a plug-in architecture
- supports hot plugging of devices and can be controlled from the command line or through D-Bus, so it can be easily integrated into existing administering solutions: for example, with Cockpit
- can be run in no-daemon mode with limited functionality (for example, no support for D-Bus, udev, tuning of newly created processes, and so on) for systems with reduced resources
- stores all its configuration cleanly in one place – in the Tuned profile – instead of having configuration on multiple places and in custom scripts

---

There should be no problem keeping `ondemand` service running or disabling it before installing `tuned`.